# Java SQL Insert a primary key in a table

Tags: java, sql

I tried to insert an id as primary key in my table with auto_increment, but everytime it shows me the error field "ID" and Column "ID" not found.

Can someone please give me the right Syntax for this?

This is what I tried:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE AUTOS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, marke varchar(255), modell varchar(255), baujahr INT)";
```

Comment: The attribute `auto_increment` takes care of the ids, you just insert all values except from the id, which is handled by the database. Or do you really want to make sure no duplicate ids are present yourself?

Comment: Yeah, I want to create a database with cars, so every car can have only one ID and no doubles. And when I insert i tired this: String sqlinsertMarke = "INSERT INTO AUTOS (MARKE, MODELL, BAUJAHR) VALUES ('" + marke + "' , '" + modell + "', '" + baujahr + "')";

Comment: Did it work? In that statement, you don't try to insert an id, so it should be working (without the single and double quotes, most likely).

Comment: Kannst du das ganze auch auf Deutsch erklären?

Comment: I could, but this is an English site… The questions and answers are not just for the one who asked and the ones who answered. But I can express myself in sql: `INSERT INTO AUTOS(MARKE, MODELL, BAUJAHR) VALUES (marke, modell, baujahr);` might be working…

Comment: Does it actually work now?

Comment: Yes, I have tried something different, but now its working :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine if it is for SQLlite
refer this [SQLlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#summary)

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE AUTOS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, marke TEXT, modell TEXT, baujahr INTEGER)";
```